# Acumatica - Can create a new web service endpoint without creating screen/UI

Tags: acumatica

I am using Acumatica and want to create new endpoint to post data API, in acumatica do we have any way to create a new web service endpoint without creating new screen/UI

Comment: You can create a Webhook handler and send the data to the generated URL for that webhook.